# Select Rows Where A Column Contains Any Result From A SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If have a table that contains a column of concatenated data using a delimiter i.e.  11111_22222_33333 (I know this is bad practice, but that's the data I have to work with)

I need to write a query that returns all rows that contain specific values of 22222 where the specific values are the result of a sub query.

So, what I am doing is follows...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IN (SELECT [Name] FROM subTable)
```

This runs but doesnt return any results as it's specifically matching 1111_2222_3333 to 2222. So what I need is a way of using a LIKE or something similar

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE (SELECT [NAME] FROM subTable)
```

gives the error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows 
=, !=, <, <=       , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

How would this be accomplished please? I am using Sql Server 2008 R2 to develop, but the solution needs to also be compatible with Server 2005

Comment: I find your username highly questionable.

Comment: Thanks all for speedy responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.* 
FROM myTable t1
join (
    SELECT distinct [Name] FROM subTable
) x
on t1.myColumn like '%' + x.[name] + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery is returning more than one value and LIKE will not work with subquery, what you  need to use is EXISTS here try this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable a 
WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM subTable b
               WHERE a.myColumn LIKE '%' + b.[NAME] + '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JOIN` with the `LIKE` clause to get the result:

```
select *
from mytable t
inner join subtable s
   on t.mycolumn like '%'+s.name+'%'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f6eb/1)

Comment: this doesnt work unless you reverse the join condition to become  t.myColumn like '%'+s.Name + '%' ?